# Find a value in object of arrays

Tags: javascript

I've created an object, in javascript, to keep some values from specific columns inside my grid, like this:

```
var Columns = { Value1: [12],
                Value2: [15]}
```

I'd like to search for a specific value and know from where is it, for instance: I received the '12' value, so i'd like to know if there is an '12' value in the Columns and the array from where it comes (that in this case, it would be Value1).

How can i do this?

Comment: what if 12 is associated with multiple items?

Comment: In this case, each column is associated with one value only

Comment: In that case not sure if the array is best choice for value type, but in that case you can use `Object.keys(Columns).find(e => Columns[e][0] == 12)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get keys with `Object.keys` method and then use `find` method to get key where value contains searched element.

```js
var Columns = {
  Value1: [12],
  Value2: [15]
}

const result = Object.keys(Columns).find(e => {
  return Columns[e].includes(12)
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Note that if 12 is associated with 2 keys, this approach will give the first key. Use `filter` instead of `find` if you need all maching keys

Comment: Or you could make this a reusable function with `const findCol = Columns => val => Object.keys(Columns).find(e => Columns[e].includes(val))` which you would use like `findCol(Columns)(15)`, and where `findCol(Columns)` might be a reusable function on its own, if the columns are fixed.

Comment: Note also that this technique will only work if you're looking for simple values like numbers or string.  If your real data involves objects or arrays, this will only work if the `Columns` object properties contain *references* to the same objects you search on.  `includes` is not particularly sophisticated.